# Open modal from outside of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am following a tutorial to create a simple modal, but the instructions explain how to open it from a button within the HTML that calls it.

```
<html>
<head>
</style>
  <!-- Don't forget to include jQuery ;) -->
  <script src="jquery.modal.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Modal HTML embedded directly into document -->
  <div id="ex1" style="display:none;">
    <p>Thanks for clicking.  That felt good.  <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a> or press ESC</p>
  </div>

  <!-- I WANT TO ACTIVATE THIS ACTION FROM A JAVASCRIPT FILE -->
  <p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open Modal</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

If I wanted to open it from a linked js file, how could I do it?

Comment: [jquery modal documentation](http://jquerymodal.com/) has all the answers you can eat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Universal solution**

For simplicity, assign an ID to that event:

```
<a id="testID" href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open Modal</a>
```

Then just trigger a click on that element.

JQuery:

```
$("#testID").click();
```

**JQuery-Modal specific solution**

Just call this to open a modal:

```
$("#testID").modal();
```

And to close programmatically, assign the ID "testClose" to some element within the modal, and run this to close the modal:

```
$("#testClose").modal({closeExisting: true});
```

**Possible improvement for more nuanced control**

I noticed that `jquery-modal` uses custom events such as "`modal:open`", so theoretically you could also call this:

```
$("#testID").trigger("modal:before-block");
$("#testID").trigger("modal:block");
$("#testID").trigger("modal:before-open");
$("#testID").trigger("modal:open");
```

However, this one did not work for me. Just use `.click()`.